# How to disable google keyboards text advises

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am making an app for teachers and students: student will see some task and he needs to write correct answer. The problem is that, if student write incorrectly (for example "moondaI" instead of "moonday") keyboard will show to user a tip - it will show that "moondaI" is written incorrectly.
How can I disable this feature inside of my app? If you know, it would be nice if you send me some tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

`setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)` in your `Activity`/`Fragment`

or in xml:

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Further explanation comes from the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

> The android:inputType attribute allows you to specify various behaviors for the input method. Most importantly, if your text field is intended for basic text input (such as for a text message), you should enable auto spelling correction with the "textAutoCorrect" value.
>
> You can combine different behaviors and input method styles with the android:inputType attribute.

---

Apparently you can also do it at the device level, thought not tried myself:

- From the Home screen, select the app drawer, then select “Settings“.
- Tap “System“. (Skip this step on some versions)
- Select “Language & keyboard“.
- Select “Virtual keyboard“.
- Choose the keyboard you are using. It’s normally named “Android“, “Google“, “gboard“, “Swype“,etc.
- Select “Text correction“.
- Enable or disable the options you want:

  - Auto-correction
  - Auto capitalization
  - Double-space period
  - Show suggestion strip
  - Next-word suggestions

[Reference](https://www.technipages.com/android-disable-auto-correct)